# docker - compose error

Tags: docker, docker-compose

This is my docker-compose.yaml

```
version: '2'
services:
  databases:
   image: mysql
   ports:
   - "3306:3306"
   environment:
   - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
   - MYSQL_USER=user
   - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
   - MYSQL_DATABASE=demodb
web:
   image: nginx
```

Error: `The Compose file ./docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Additional properties are not allowed('web' was unexpected)`

And on the bottom part it says that this is maybe because of the docker-compose version, but on docker website it says that docker on windows come with docker-compose and don't need to be installed separately.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue is your indentation for `web`, please align it with the same level as `databases` service as per below. Then I manage to run `docker-compose up`

```
version: '2'
services:
   databases:
     image: mysql
     ports:
       - "3306:3306"
     environment:
       - MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=password
       - MYSQL_USER=user
       - MYSQL_PASSWORD=password
       - MYSQL_DATABASE=demodb
   web:
     image: nginx
```

Comment: Thank you, I don't know how I missed that.